# How to play video that is saved in the folder without using any extensions - Yii2 advanced app?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to this Yii2 framework and wanted to try and play a demo video that I have placed inside "frontend/web/assets/videos/myvideo.mp4". Now I am trying to play this file using HTML's video tag. But nothing comes up. How and where to store the video files in assets folder. I don't intend to use any extensions for now.

I tried the following code:

```
<?php use frontend\assets\AppAsset; ?>

<video width="100%" height="400" controls>
     <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I just want to play the video that is already in my assets folder for now. But didn't work. Do I need to add any line of code in AppAssets.php file ? If so, what ?

TIA. Appreciate all the suggestions.

Comment: You should provide your AppAsset code as well to improve your answers.

Comment: you should place your video inside the web folder and access it with `/myvideo.mp4` or `/videos/myvideo.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you appear to use the fronend\asset\Appset but you did not register it.

```
<?php
$asset = \frontend\assets\AppAsset::register($this); 
$filepath = $asset->baseUrl . '/myvideo.mp4'; 
?>
<video width="100%" height="400" controls>
     <source src="<?= $filepath ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks Jairus. Make minor change in the file path in your given code above and that works for me. Thanks much for helping it out. Really appreciate. Thanks.